# Pay-per-install type mechanism for iPad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, medical

I am a developer of an iPad application that can be used to expedite the transfer of information from patients to physicians.  We are marketing to a wide variety of multispecialty adolescent clinics, and we are monetizing the app through a monthly subscription fee.

Unfortunately, I realized that hospitals will be able to get a single iTunes account and download the application on multiple iPads and distribute them to doctors... thereby allowing them to bypass the pay-per-physician model we originally envisioned.

Is there anyway to prevent hospitals from doing this?  Is there a pay-per-install mechanism that can be utilized?

Comment: You could require that the individual physicians sign into the app with a username / password when they start it. They could still share this password, but at least this way you could track this and ban shared accounts.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make an in-app purchase that will deposit a DRM token on the device, and use that to validate users to prevent account sharing. The problem with this approach is that the user would have to pay again if he deletes the app for whichever reason. (And could, hypothethically, be circumvented by tampering with backups but that's a less trivial attack than sharing an iTunes account.)

Comment: Are you collecting payments yourself, or do you need the appstore to handle them for you?

Comment: Need appstore to handle payments

Comment: Do you have a service in the cloud or would you be willing to have one?

Comment: Service is not in the cloud; we might be willing to do one, but as of current it seems like an unnecessary expense if there are alternative ways of solving this.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the app free and then make the user buy an in-app purchase. You would need to make it the consumable type, because that runs out(after one month, it could, at least) and is on a per device basis.

Answer (score 0):

Although deprecated; you could use the device's UUID for device identification. It will be unique and constant for that physical device.

```
NSString* uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Post it to a simple webservice for validation, if it returns used, alert the user and restrict use (and probably some information about a refund/fix).